# Error opening python socket for panda-datareader and Yahoo finance API

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

So I'm new here folks and have hit the wall off the bat. I was following along with lesson 2 of "Intro and Getting Stock Price Data - Python Programming for Finance" by sentdex on YouTube "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2BrpKpWwT2A".

I've installed pandas and `pandas-datareader` current versions successfully.
My code compiles but crashes when trying to open connection it appears. Can anyone advise?

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')

start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

df = web.DataReader('TSLA', 'yahoo', start, end)
print(df.head())
```

---

The errors I see are (of course followed by other errors during handling:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\S\App\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 141, in _new_conn
>       (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
>     File "C:\Users\S\App\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 60, in create_connection
>       for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
>     File "C:\Users\S\App\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\socket.py", line 728, in getaddrinfo
>       for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
>   socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Answer (score 0):

FYI All, I got help from the Python board. Install fix-yahoo-finance.